# Proving $||A||_2 \leq || [A|x]||_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I would like to show $||A||_2 \leq || [A|x]_2||$ where $x$ is any vector of appropriate size. My thinking is using column spaces and the fact that the column space can only increase, not decrease, but am not confident on this idea.

Comment: $\lVert A\rVert_2^2$ is the sum of the squares of the absolute values of the entries of $A$.  If you include more entries, then this sum increases.

Comment: @LSpice Isn't that the Frobenius norm as opposed to the 2-norm?

Comment: The Frobenius norm *is* what I'd call the 2-norm.  What do you use?

Comment: (I also assumed you meant $\lVert[A\vert x]\rVert_2$, rather than what I see now is $\lVert[A\vert x]_2\rVert$, whose meaning I don't know if it's really what was intended.)

Comment: @LSpice You are correct, that is a typo sorry. The matrix 2-norm is defined as the usual $p$-norm on matrices.

Comment: Right, and the Frobenius norm is what I'd call the usual 2-norm on matrices.  In other words, I'd expect the $p$-norm of $A$ to be $\sqrt[p]{\sum_{i = 1}^{\#\text{rows}} \sum_{j = 1}^{\#\text{columns}} \lvert a_{i j}\rvert^p}$ (which specialises to the Frobenius norm when $p = 2$).  What do you use?

Comment: @LSpice $||A||_p = \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_p}{||x||_p}$

Comment: Ah, the operator norm.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be $m \times n$, and let $v$ be any non-$0$ vector in $\mathbb R^n$.  Then, with hopefully obvious ‘padding’ notation, $[A\vert x](v; 0) = A v$, so
$$
\frac{\lVert A v\rVert_2}{\lVert v\rVert_2}
= \frac{\lVert[A\vert x](v; 0)\rVert_2}{\lVert(v; 0)\rVert_2}
\le \lVert[A\vert x]\rVert_2.
$$
Taking suprema gives the result.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain the notation sorry?

Comment: $(v; 0)$ means to make an $n$-dimensional vector into an ($n + 1$)-dimensional one by sticking a $0$ on the end.

Comment: Thanks, I get it know